# A link to search bar with the cursor

Tags: search, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a search bar on my web page. What do I use as the src="" if I want to make the link jump to the input section of the search bar, with the cursor blinking there too. I'm using twitter bootstrap 3 if that helps.

Comment: I think you mean href not src for anchor tags (links).

Comment: Yes, I meant href thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have an input with an id of search like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" id="search">
```

Then you can do this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('search').focus();" class="btn btn-primary">go to search</a>
```

The preferred way to do this would be with an event handler (versus inline as I've shown above) for maintainability.  That would look something like this if you're using jQuery (which I'm just assuming you are since you've marked this with a Twitter Bootstrap tag):

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary searchlink">go to search</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.searchlink').on('click', function() {
    $('#search').focus();
  }):
});
```

Comment: Yes yes my buddy at work found that adding that badboy `$('#search').focus();` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use html label for your input.

```
<input type='text' id='search'/>
<label for='search'>Search</label>
```